# ReactJs component syntax, whats the difference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning Reactjs, I am trying to write a basic component, can anyone tell me why this component syntax:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class AboutPage extends Component {
render: function() {
    const { page } = this.props;
    return (
        <div className="blog-post">
            <h2 className="blog-post-title">{page.title.rendered}</h2>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup(page.content.rendered)} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Is different to this component?

```
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});
```

Why use `export default class` instead of just `var HelloMessage = React.createClass({` ?

Comment: "instead of just" --- those are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `createClass` syntax was the original way to create React components, but it seems like it's being phased out in favour of the `class` syntax and stateless functional components.

There are a few key differences to be aware of if you're upgrading a component from `createClass` a `class`.

## Initial State & Default Props

With `createClass` you could declare methods that would return the initial state and default properties for a given component.

```
React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { foo: 'bar' };
  },
  getDefaultProps() {
    return { baz: 'qux' };
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(
      this.state, // => { foo: 'bar' }
      this.props  // => { baz: 'qux' }
    );
  }
});
```

Both have been changed for the class syntax. Instead, you assign your initial state inside the constructor.

```
class extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { foo: 'bar' };
  }
}
```

And you declare the default props as a static property.

```
class Qux extends React.Component {}
Qux.defaultProps = { baz: 'qux' };
```

## Mixins

The `createClass` syntax supports a concept called mixins, which allow you to provide other code which augments the existing lifecycle methods.

```
const logOnMount = {
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('Mounted!', new Date());
  }
};

React.createClass({
  mixins: [logOnMount]
});
```

Any component using the `logOnMount` mixin will log a timestamp to the console whenever it is mounted.

There's no support for mixins with the `class` syntax, but you can use [higher-order components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750) to achieve the same things.

```
function logOnMount(Component) {
  return function(props) {
    console.log('Mounted!', new Date());
    return (
      <Component {...props} />
    );
  }
}
```

## Autobinding

The `createClass` syntax provided some handy auto-binding so that you could safely pass component methods as callbacks and not have to worry about ending up with the wrong context for `this`.

```
React.createClass({
  bar() {
    return true;
  },
  foo() {
    this.bar();
  },
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.foo}>Click</button>;
  }
});
```

The `onClick` handler will try and invoke `this.foo` with `this` set as the event that was triggered, but because `this.foo` was autobound to have the correct context, there's no error.

Here's the same example, but with classes.

```
class extends React.Component {
  bar() {
    return true;
  }
  foo() {
    this.bar(); // Error - undefined is not a function
  }
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.foo}>Click</button>;
  }
}
```

The `foo` method ends up with `this` set to the event, which doesn't have a `bar` property.

To get around this, you'll need to explicitly bind the methods in the constructor, or invoke the method from inside an arrow function.

```
constructor() {
  this.foo = this.foo.bind(this);
}

// or

render() {
  return <button onClick={e => this.foo()}>Click</button>;
}
```

Comment: `class extends...` is ES6 right? or does that also work for ES5?

Comment: It's just an anonymous Es6 class.

Answer (score 3):

First, there's also another option that you haven't mentioned:

```
export default function AboutPage(props) {
  const { page } = props;
  const pageContentMarkup = createMarkup(page.content.rendered);
  return (
    <div className="blog-post">
      <h2 className="blog-post-title">{page.title.rendered}</h2>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={pageContentMarkup} />
    </div>
  );
```

This one is very terse and emphasises that your component is stateless.

Secondly, the class syntax notably doesn't allow using mixins. Some say this is a feature, not a bug, and we should actually move away from mixins.

[Dan Abramov makes an argument](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.cfe7y7ev7) that mixins don't compose well, and proposes higher order components as an alternative. "Higher order component" is a fancy term for a function that takes a React component class and returns another class that some behaviour added. Higher order components can be seen as "decorators". You apply them in order to a component and they will each still do their own thing without even needing to know about each other.

This looks like a good reason to leave behind the old syntax and move forward with classes.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you can't just use this wholesale, due to the use of `this.createMarkup`. You'd need to move the method away from the instance and define it explicitly as a function somewhere.

Comment: @DanPrince Oops, I missed that `this`. Thanks! Amended

Answer (score 1):

The `class` syntax is new in ES2015, you can read about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

The `React.createClass` function exists because javascript before ES2015 didn't have support for classes.

There are a couple of differences for react specifically, which are detailed in [the react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes), but personally, I would use the new class syntax if you're able to.